# Flask can't find 'password' field when using SQLAlchemy's hybrid_property

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm learning Flask, and I'm trying out the [exploreflask tutorial](https://exploreflask.com/users.html). My register form is not working. The error is in **server.py** and says:

```
password = form.password.data

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'password'
```

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy's `declarative_base`, so I believe the `hybrid_property` on the password should work fine, but that is not the case!

models.py:

```
from flask.ext.login import UserMixin
from flask.ext.bcrypt import Bcrypt
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from database import Base

# Base is using Flask-SqlAlchemy's declarative_base()
class User(Base, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(120), unique=True)
    _password = Column(String(120))

    def __init__(self, name=None, email=None):
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.name)

    @hybrid_property
    def password(self):
        return self._password

    @password.setter
    def _set_password(self, plaintext):
        self._password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(plaintext)

    def verify_password(self, plaintext):
        return bcrypt.check_password_hash(self._password, plaintext)
```

forms.py:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField
from wtforms.fields.html5 import EmailField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired

class RegisterForm(Form):
    email = EmailField('email', validators=[InputRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[InputRequired()])
```

server.py:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(
            email = form.email.data,
            password = form.password.data
        )

        db_session.add(user)
        db_session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('login.html'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

I'm not sure what's wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The hybrid\_property decorator: can't set attribute error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62249208/the-hybrid-property-decorator-cant-set-attribute-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In server.py you are initializing a User instance with email and password. 
However, your constructor for User class accepts only arguments name and email.

So you should change your constructor that it accepts password as well.

```
def __init__(self, name=None, email=None, password=None)
    #your constructor logic
```